How to handle fatal error when no switch case is hit?
Sometimes I do this in a switch statement when it's truly a fatal error and program shouldn't continure:
/* INSIDE A FUNCTION THAT RETURNS AN INT */
switch(variable)
{
case 1: return 1;
case 2: return 2;
default: abort(); /* maybe print a message or log or something*/
}

I realise recently while compiling stuff that I get warnings about not all paths returning something in the function. I don't like these warnings because it pollutes the output. Should I return just any value after the abort to silence the compiler warnings? What would this do? Should I throw an exception instead?

What language-standard are you on? Since c++11, abort is marked [[noreturn]], meaning any compiler after can and will use this information to determine that the default-path won't return, and thus not issue a warning. If for some reason abort isn't marked [[noreturn]], but you are on c++11, you could make your own wrapper.

The proper method is to pass an error status variable (by reference) and optionally an std::ostream by reference.  The error status will be set to either "successful" or to a value that indicates the issue (value out of range).  The std::ostream is to provide the caller with a detailed explanation.  You may want to throw an exception; there may already exist an exception for out of range values.

If the need is just to express that no other case can possibly occur, you can call std::unreachable() from the default: case. It is specifically designed to indicate that a certain branch of code is not possible to reach.

@FrançoisAndrieux Interesting, that's interesting, C++23. The thing with C++ is that I don't think you can reliably use features that new in a reliable way across compilers. I mean, for Android I still have to use c++17. Hell even the newest Clang compiler for Emscripten didn't recognise the std::date library which is supposed c++20.

Here's one method I like:
enum class my_method_error 
{
  SUCCESS,
  OUT_OF_RANGE,
};

int my_method(int the_variable, my_method_error& error_code, std::ostream& details)
{
  int return_value{0};
  switch(the_variable)
  {
    case 1: return_value = 2; break;
    case 2: return_value = 3; break;
    //...
    default:
     return_value = my_method_error::OUT_OF_RANGE;
  }
  return return_value;
}  

There are other methods, such as throwing an exception.
You may want to include __FILE__ and __LINE__ in your detailed description, to aid in debugging.
